# Не работает регулярное выражение на поиск кириллицы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Написал простую регулярку на фильтрацию строк, содержащих русские слова.
`#^[\p{Cyrillic}\s0-9\-]+$#`
Потестил её на https://regex101.com/ - работает.
Добавил в свой код - не работает... Не могу понять почему, нашёл онлайн компилятор PHP, потестил на нём код - действительно не работает!

```
$res = "вопрос";
if(preg_match("#^[\p{Cyrillic}\s0-9\-]+$#", $res)){
  echo 'Good';
} else {
  echo 'Bad';
}
```

Выдаёт Bad, хотя в переменной $res только русские символы, должна писать Good. Почему?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07479a932b8b77d28cb07bc36a9ad906ff1da22e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавь модификатор `#^[\p{Cyrillic}\s0-9\-]+$#u`

```
$res = "вопрос";
if(preg_match("#^[\p{Cyrillic}\s0-9\-]+$#u", $res)){
  echo 'Good';
} else {
  echo 'Bad';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что нужна регулярка для поиска русских слов в тексте. Как вариант можно так:

```
$res = "вопрос";
var_dump( preg_match("/([а-я]+)/ui", $res) );
```

модификатор «u» позволяет работать с текстом в кодировке UTF-8, а «i» -отвечает за регистронезависимый поиск.

Ну и для поиска всех русских слов, используем preg_match_all()